# Identify the isometry with a metric

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the French railway metric $d_{FR}$. Let $$S =\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 = \frac{1}{4}\right\}\;.$$ Describe the restriction to S of the metric $d_{FR}$. Identify it up to isometry, with some metric.

My strategy / thoughts

I can see that $S$ is all of the boundary points on some circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$I think the only metric that could be defined is with $d(x,y) = \cos^{-1}(x,y)$ where the distance is the distance between $x,y$ on the great circle connecting them. But, there is a restriction that they all lie on that radius. I am not sure what it means to say identify it up to an isometry. The only thing that comes to mind is to say that it is some sort of rotation perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

If $x = y$, then $d(x,y) = 0$, but if $x \neq y$, then $d(x,y) = d_2(x,0) + d_2(y,0) = 1$ (where $d_2$ is the standard Euclidean metric). Note this also covers the case $x = -y$.

That is, you have

$$
d(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 &: x \ne y \\
 0 &: x = y\end{cases}
$$

Does this look familiar?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: I think that you’ve misunderstood what’s being asked for. Start by computing the distances between some points of $S$ in the French railway metric. What do you notice about them? If that doesn’t help, check the spoiler-protected block below.

> They’re all $1$. Do you know another metric on $S$ with that property?

Comment: I drew out $S$ to obtain a circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$. From there I measure points $x,y \in S$ where $x \ne y$ and I get that they are $d(x,y)=1$ If $x=y$ then $d(x,y)=0$. This is exactly the discrete metric. \[d(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : x \ne y \\
       0 & : x = y
     \end{array}\right\].    So is that what it means to identify it up to an isometry?

Comment: @Zeta10: Yes, it is. (And note that you don’t literally have to measure: if $0$ is the origin, and $p$ and $q$ are any two points on $S^1$, then $d(p,q)$ is simply the sum of the Euclidean distances from $p$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $q$, even if $p$ and $q$ are on the same straight line through $0$. The Euclidean distances from $p$ and $q$ to $0$ are both $\frac12$, so $d(p,q)=1$ in every case (assuming that $p\ne q$, of course).)

Comment: Right. Thank you. That was exactly the case. Since every point on $S$ is the same distance from the origin, it was clear. The only time the distance was not $1$ is when considering the distance from the point to itself, which is obviously $0$

Comment: @Zeta10: You’re welcome. (It really is a rather sneaky way to get the discrete metric!)